# Gluing up points of Torus to get a new 2-manifold.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, quotient-spaces, low-dimensional-topology

Lets define Torus as set all pair (z<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>2</sub>) where z<sub>1</sub>,z<sub>2</sub> $\in$ $\mathbb{C}$ and |z<sub>1</sub>| = 1,|z<sub>2</sub>| = 1.

Now if we glue together
(z<sub>1</sub>, z<sub>2</sub>) $\sim$ (-z<sub>1</sub>, -z<sub>2</sub>)

What the new 2-manifold look like?
My guess is its a non-orientable one,Klein bottle maybe?

Comment: should it be $|z_1|,|z_2|\leq 1$ ?

Comment: Torus is product of two circles,  | z | = 1 are all points of unit circle in the complex plane,  isn't it ?

Comment: What did you try to confirm or to refute your guess? Did you at least try to determine if the map $-Id$ restricted to the torus is orientation preserving/reversing?

Comment: I drew some pictures, by cutting two small cylinder from Torus i tried to glue just their boundaries, and  i found cross caps, may be im wrong

Comment: Hint: Work out first the quotient of $S^1$ by the equivalence relation $z\sim -z$.